# Append checkbox together with datasnapshot in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to add checkbox for each and every rows but when i try to run the code, something like this shows "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead of a checkbox

```
    function BSIT(){

        $("#stdlist").empty();
        var chyear = $('#chyear').val();
        $("#showtxt").html(chyear);


      var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";

      var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("course/BSIT");
      ref.orderByChild("Year").equalTo(chyear).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var childData = snapshot.val();
            $("#stdlist").append("<tr> <td>" +  checkbox + "</td><td>" + childData.StudentId +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.FirstName +" "+ childData.Lastname +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.Address +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.Gender +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.Age +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.Phone +
                                "</td><td>" + childData.Year +
                                "</td></tr>" 

                );

      });
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2s3m.png)

Comment: Show some more code. How you getting `childData`, and the value inside it.

Comment: I have edited my code above @Hareesh

Comment: and what is the expected value inside `childData.StudentId`

Comment: A string @Hareesh

Comment: confirm `StudentId` spelled correctly in firebase.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the ChildData, I just cant figure it out how to add that checkbox for each and every row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function BSIT(){

    $("#stdlist").empty();
    var chyear = $('#chyear').val();
    $("#showtxt").html(chyear);

  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("course/BSIT");
  ref.orderByChild("Year").equalTo(chyear).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var childData = snapshot.val();
        $("#stdlist").append("<tr> <td>" + '<input type="checkbox">'+ "</td><td>" + childData.StudentId +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.FirstName +" "+ childData.Lastname +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.Address +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.Gender +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.Age +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.Phone +
                            "</td><td>" + childData.Year +
                            "</td></tr>" 

            );

  });
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Save my life :) Thanks @Prateek Agrawal.